# Bash how to get full script name from PID

Tags: php, bash, ps

I have this php function that checks the script's name from the given PID, and compares it to itself.

```
function isRunning($pid) {
    $filename = exec('ps -p '.$pid.' -o "%c"');
    $self = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    return ($filename == $self) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

From what I know, I usually use this command to get the script name from the PID:

```
ps -o PID -o "%c"
```

It returns me the filename, but only the first 15 characters.
Since my script's name is

> daily_system_check.php

the function always returns FALSE, because it's comparing itself with

> daily_system_ch

Is there another bash command for Centos 6 that will return me script's full name?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what is your OS, but in Ubuntu Linux I can see full name of the script with adding  `--context` to the ps call:

```
# ps -p 17165 --context
  PID CONTEXT                  COMMAND
17165 unconfined               /bin/bash ./testing_long_script_name.sh
#
```

Comment: --context returns the whole path of the filename. That can get me the filename by using php basename() function, but curious to see if there's a simpler bash command.

Comment: It looks like you might have to parse that a bit.
You can shorter the output to just the "command" by using just `ps -ocmd -p PID`

Answer (score 2):

read the the proc `cmdline` file:

```
cat /proc/$pid/cmdline | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\0"} {print $2}'
```

Comment: That's close. It returns the filepath but not just the filename. I could use php basename() function to get the filename but wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no flag or collumn in "ps" command to show the whole filename without the filepath or it being cutoff. PHP's [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) gets the job done.

```
function isRunning($pid) {
    $filename = basename(exec('ps -o cmd= '.$pid));
    $self = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    return ($filename == $self) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```